# 500 ошибка при отправке формы

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, никак не могу отловить из-за чего 500 ошибка вылезает при отправке формы.
Вылезает при добавлении в обработчик такого куска кода:

```
if ($id == 'calculator' && !empty($_POST['calculator-data'])) {
    $out = "\n";
    parse_str($_POST['calculator-data'], $calculatorData);
    foreach ($calculatorData as $index => $params) {
        $out .= $params['title']. "\n";
        $out .= "--------------------------------------\n";
        unset($params['title']);
        foreach ($params as $name => $value) {
            $out .= "\t" . strip_tags($value) . "\n";
        }
        $out .= "\n";
    }
    $data['windows'] = $out;
}
```

Comment: открывайте error_log на сервере (если там апач) и смотрите, что там. Скорее всего, там будет warnings с указанием номера строки.

Comment: error_log я на хостинге не нашел. Отписал им, может, че ответят.
А может еще какая нужна инфа, чтобы решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пишите с использованием фреймворка/CMS? Если да, то, возможно, система отлавливает ошибки (даже fatal) и заносит их в собственный лог, показывая при этом ошибку сервера.

Внимательно посмотрите на Ваш код.

```
$id == 'calculator'
```

У Вас `$id`, где-нибудь объявлен? Иначе:

```
if (isset($id) && $id == 'calculator' && !empty($_POST['calculator-data'])) {
  ...
}
```

Далее, меня смущает:

```
parse_str($_POST['calculator-data'], $calculatorData);
```

Т.к. результат отдаётся по ссылке, то необходимо заранее объявить переменную, а именно:

```
$calculatorData = array();
parse_str($_POST['calculator-data'], $calculatorData);
```

Comment: Тааак, спасибо, посмотрим

Comment: Какие-то чудеса. Сегодня открыл, ничего не правил, все работает, никаких ошибок не вылезает.

Comment: @romeo, нет необходимости объявлять переменную. Так как в момент передачи она `null`, ее значение будет перезаписано на результат, но при этом она уже существует в тот момент, когда написана

Comment: @stck Вы правы. Перепутал с `array_shift`, `array_pop`,..., где, собственно, этот трюк не пройдёт.